# Calculate PRESS statistic

Tags: r, regression

[image]I have started but I am stuck, I need assistance. I do not know how to do some of the parts, which makes me not able to finish. I have attached the problem that I am working on.

Here is my code :

```
pressftn<- function(r,n,pi) {
  
  press <- Null
  
  for (i in 1:r) { 
    
       # (iii) Repeat (ii) for i = 1, · · · , n and save.
       #(i) Generate the data (X1i,X2i, Y ) from the following linear regression model:
  
     x1i<-runif(n, 0.5, 1.5)
     x2i<-runif(n, 0.5, 1.5)
    
     rbern(n, pi)
     ei<-rnorm(n, 0, 0.5) + rnorm(n, 0, 2)
  
     yi<- 0.5 + 2*x1i - 3*x2i  + ei 
  
     data <- data.frame(x1i, x2i, yi)
  

     #(ii) Exclude the ith observation, run regression analysis with the remaining n − 1, and calculate the             prediction error for the ith observation

     regression <- lm(yi~x1i+x2i, data=data)
     regression
    
   
    pred = predict(regression, newdata=data.frame[i,]) 


     Press[i, ] <- 
     
     # (iv) Repeat (i) - (iii) r times and save PRESS(1), · · · , PRESS(r).
     Press[i, ]
    }
  
     return(Press)
}

results <- pressftn(50, 30, 0.5)
write.table(results, file="press.txt", sep=" ", row.names = F, col.names = F, quote=F)

set.seed(32816)
pressftn(50,30,0.5)

# (v) Create histogram of the r PRESS values. Show the proportions for the histogram, include proper labels and titles, and use the rainbow color scheme with 10 breaks.

hist(press, breaks=10, probability=TRUE, col=rainbow(press), xlab="press", ylab = "proportions", main="Histogram press")
```

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the logic of the program because you need to have effectively 2 loops: to calculate *PRESS* value itself, then obtain the *PRESS* vector to draw the histogram, you used only one loop. For calculation of mixture error just adding up two component of error won't work, you need to use `ifelse`. Corrected typos and mistakes as well (like `Null` usage, missing subsetting in Step iii etc.). See the code below:

```
pressftn <- function(r,n,pi) {
  press <- numeric(r)
  
  for (j in 1:r) { 
    # (iii) Repeat (ii) for i = 1, · · · , n and save.
    #(i) Generate the data (X1i,X2i, Y ) from the following linear regression model:
    
    x1i <- runif(n, 0.5, 1.5)
    x2i <- runif(n, 0.5, 1.5)
    berns <- rbinom(n, 1, pi)
    ns1 <- rnorm(n, 0, 0.5)
    ns2 <- rnorm(n, 0, 2)
    
    ei <- ifelse(berns, ns1, ns2)
    
    yi <- 0.5 + 2 * x1i - 3 * x2i  + ei 
    
    data <- data.frame(x1i, x2i, yi)
    
    #(ii) Exclude the ith observation, run regression analysis with the remaining n − 1, 
    # and calculate the
    # prediction error for the ith observation
    
    yi_min_y_i_hat <- vapply(seq(nrow(data)), function(i) {
      regression <- lm(yi ~ x1i + x2i, data = data[-i, ])
      pred <- predict(regression, newdata = data[i, c("x1i", "x2i")])
      pred - data[i, "yi"]
    }, 0)
    
    press[j] <- sum(yi_min_y_i_hat^2)
  }
  
  return(press)
}

set.seed(32816)
prs <- pressftn(50, 300, 0.5)

hist(prs)
```

Output:

[image: hist]